# Disable interaction with main window, while other window is open

Tags: objective-c, macos, mainwindow, keywindow

I have a main window where all the work is done. 
When i open the preference panel I would like to freeze the main windows as long as the preference panel is open.
For example iTunes: as soon as i open the preferences i just can interact with preference panel and nothing else.

Is there an easy way to archive this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
[NSApp runModalForWindow:theWindow];
```

Comment: Thanks!! ...and `[NSApp stopModal];` to go back to normal :-)